# bazel cannot find my android sdk path properly

Tags: sdk, environment-variables, bazel, tensorflow-lite

I want to generate **tensorflow lite AAR** file using **bazel** command. According to the tensorflow document [Android quick start](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/android), I install bazel successfully and then, I set **ANDROID_SDK_HOME** and **ANDROID_NDK_HOME** in the system enviroment variables as follows :

**ANDROID_SDK_HOME** = 'G:\IT\AndroidStudioSdk\AndroidStudio'

**ANDROID_NDK_HOME** = 'G:\IT\AndroidStudioSdk\AndroidStudio\ndk\android-ndk-r17c'

**NOTE:** I put my android sdk manually in G drive, because I didn't have enough space in C.

And after that, I configure **WORKSPACE** using **configure.cmd** file in my tensorflow root directory (C:\Users\username\tensorflow). But, when I want to build **TensorFlow Lite AAR** with this command :

[image]

I face this Error:

[image]

Apparently, bazel cannot find path properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NDK, SDK locations should be expressed using the forward slashes `/` instead of back-slashes `\` as the path separator symbol. So, in your case:

```
set ANDROID_SDK_HOME = 'G:/IT/AndroidStudioSdk/AndroidStudio'
set ANDROID_NDK_HOME = 'G:/IT/AndroidStudioSdk/AndroidStudio/ndk/android-ndk-r17c'
```

And then run the `configure.cmd` script to use those values when setting up the Android WORKSPACE.